# Record information from the site after the button is clicked, in a txt file on the githab

Tags: php, html, github, web

`

```
<body>
        <form action = "" method = "">
            
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            <?php
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            ?>
        </form> 
</body>
```

I enter information into the field, click the button, and the information should end up in file.txt

Maybe the problem was that github doesn't support file swapping, but I doubt it

```
            $str = "Name: " .$name."\n"."Email: ".$email;
            ?>
            <?php
            $fp = fopen("info.txt", "a+")
            fwrite($fp,$str);
            fclose($fp);
```

This is what the attempt looked like.

Comment: How is Github related? Are you "hosting" that site on Github pages? (Because they don't support PHP afaik)

Comment: Information from the github is sent to the hosting

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What information from github? Your php code collects form data from the user. Again, for clarity, github pages does not support executing php code, so if that's what you're trying to do, you'll need to host it somewhere else. Always check that the hosting environment you want to use actually supports the code you want to execute...this is simple logic

Comment: You don't quite understand, my site code is on a githab, the repository is connected to the site hosting and working.
https://phpiotsad.azurewebsites.net/?name=&last_name=&login=&email=&password=&password=

Comment: So it's hosted somewhere else? In that case the location of your source control repository is completely irrelevant as far as I can see, its unclear why you mentioned it. So then what is the specific issue you're experiencing? What debugging have you done? You can't save the data directly back to github, if that's what you're thinking. Your php can only save the data back to the filesystem on its hosting environment. To save data elsewhere you'd need to connect via the API of the relevant service.

Comment: Fyi, you won't have access to `$_POST` if you use `method = ""` in your `<form>`. Use `method="post"`

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand correctly. You have some php code that is saved into a github project and you run that code via Azure websites.
If my above line is correct, then this is what (I think) is happening:

> Azure is connected to your github project and pulls your php code from there, then it runs your web page (with your form).

There is an important difference from Azure to Github. GIT is used **ONLY** to store your code (php in this case). AzureWebsites takes that code (is making a copy of your code) and runs that code (probably in a container) - let's say it uses Apache as a web server and PHP to run your code. So when you access the webpage you access AzureWebsites (Apache/php) with a **COPY** of your code from github. When you save the file (from php) you are still on the webserver (azurewebsites).  You can not save that file back into GIT, since GIT and AzureWebsites are 2 different entities.  I know it might sound weird, but GIT is not connected to your *running* php code and it will never be.

Even though from your perspective you put the code into GIT and run it in AZURE, it does not work in reverse: azure will not be able to push code to GIT (actually to be honest, in theory this could be possible, but the level of complexity, and security risks are too high to even start explaining.)

After reading my above explanation, take a look at the picture below, maybe it makes sense. If you have questions, please feel free to comment, I hope I can clear this for you.
Regards.

[image]